# C++ - Linked List - Unable to create a temporary node

Tags: c++, variables, linked-list, smart-pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a temporary variable 'p' in my print function. 
I'm getting one compiler error and 2 warnings that I don't know how to deal with.

Most functions left out for filling later once I have a handle on the print function.

I've also redefined cout<<&n to print out the values of the linked list.

```
unique_ptr.h||In instantiation of 'typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Node; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<Node, std::default_delete<Node> >*}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<Node>]':|

Deque.cpp|46|required from here|

/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h|787|error: invalid conversion from 'const std::unique_ptr<Node>*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|
Node.h|15|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Node::Node(int)'|
```

||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Node.h"
#include "Deque.cpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& n) {
  return out << &n << ": " << n.val << " -> " << n.next.get();
}

int main()
{

      return 0;
}
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
 public:
 Node(const Node& n) : val{n.val}, next{}
  {
  }
 Node(int v, std::unique_ptr<Node> n) : val{v}, next{move(n)}
  {
  }
 Node(int v) : val{v}
  {
  }

 private:
  int val = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;

  friend class Deque;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&);
};

#endif
```

Deque.h

```
#include <memory>

class Deque{
    public:
        Deque() = default;
        Deque(const Deque&);
        ~Deque(); //must use constant space
        Deque& operator=(const Deque&); //we can use assignment in this assignement lols.



        void print_queue(const std::string& label) const; //prints all nodes in queue,
        //together with pointers to head and tail and also size of queue.
        //routine calls the node output function - not tested



    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> tail;

    friend Node;


};
```

Deque.cpp

```
#include "Deque.h"
#include <memory>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


void Deque::print_queue( const std::string& label) const
{
std::unique_ptr<Node> p = std::make_unique<Node>(&head);
cout<< "This is the linked list: " << endl;

while ( p != NULL)
    {
        cout<< &head;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've also tried `std::unique_ptr<Node> p = head;` which results in a different error `use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)` Although I feel that this way is more proper than the former.

Comment: Way too much code. Please narrow it down to the smallest, self-contained, compilable example that still reproduces the error.

Comment: will do, thank you. - the deed has been done.

Comment: why you declare insertion operator private?

Comment: @TigerCode: I think it could still be smaller :) Do you even need `Deque` class, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code there are two things I think you should probably read more about.
The first is references and the multiple meaning of the `&` operator in C++.

When you have a function like this:

```
void f(const Type& param);
```

it means that `param` is a reference to a `const Type`. The `&` in this case declares `param` a reference. If you want to call this method, you do it like this:

```
Type value;
f(value);
```

Notice that the parameter `value` is passed as-is, without any other qualifiers. If instead you try to call the function like:

```
f(&value);
```

then the `&` means `address of` and `&value` is not a reference, it's a pointer, which requires the function to look like:

```
void f(Type *param);
```

This explains the error you're getting when you write this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> p = std::make_unique<Node>(&head);
```

Here `head` is a `std::unique_ptr<Node>` so `&head` is a pointer to `unique_ptr<Node>`. This is exactly what the error message is telling you:

```
invalid conversion from 'const std::unique_ptr<Node>*' to 'int'
```

It's trying to call the `Node` constructor taking an `int` parameter and can't convert the pointer to `unique_ptr` to `int`.

The second thing you should read more on is `unique_ptr` itself. In short, `unique_ptr` is a single-ownership smart pointer, it can't be copied, you can't have to `unique-ptr`s managing the same object.
This is why you can't do this in your code:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> p = head;
```

The error message in this case basically tells you there is no copy constructor for `unique_ptr`.

Because you can't copy `unique_ptr`s, traversing a linked list implemented the way you're writing it can't be done the usual homework-like fashion you're trying to do it in. You will also have to think harder when you'll implement the other operations on your list, like inserting or deleting a node.

But let's stick to traversing the list. You can't copy `unique_ptr`s, so you'll have to access them using either references or raw pointers.

**Using references**

This method is also not straightforward because references can't be "reassigned" after they're defined. So you could try to do it recursively, e.g.:

```
void printNodeAndGoNext(const std::unique_ptr<Node> &node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        std::cout << node->value;
        printAndGoNext(node->next);
    }
}

void print()
{
    printNodeAndGoNext(head);
}
```

This uses only references to `unique_ptr`s, it doesn't need to create any copies of nodes.
But as always with recursive functions, it doesn't scale. Don't do this.

**Using pointers**

You can use raw non-owning pointers to either the `unique_ptr`s themselves or the underlying nodes they're managing.

The first version would look like this:

```
void print()
{
    const std::unique_ptr<Node> *node = &head;
    while(node)
    {
        std::cout << (*node)->value;
        node = &((*node)->next);
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the `*`s and the `&`s and the actual data types you're getting.

The second version, using raw pointers to the actual nodes:

```
void print()
{
    const Node *node = head.get();
    while (node)
    {
        std::cout << node->value;
        node = node->next.get();
    }
}
```

Between all of these, the last version would be the preferred one. Using raw non-owning pointers to objects managed by owning `unique_ptr`s is perfectly fine and safe if you're a little careful.

**Disclaimer**

The code fragments above are only to illustrate the points, you'll have to adapt the ideas and actually write the code for your situation.

**Future problems you'll face**

I already mentioned some of them. You'll have to implement the standard list operations, like insert and delete, using the unique properties of `unique_ptr`.

Another aspect to think about (and fix) has to do with recursion again. More specifically, what happens when you have a list implemented like this and which has more that a few nodes (thousands of nodes, tens of thousands, millions etc) and you want to destroy it?